Can we use python f-string placeholder with index number?
How can we achieve the following in Python 3.6 using f-string (instead of using format()) method?
quantity = 3
itemno = 567
price = 49
myorder = "I want {0} pieces of item number {1} for {2:.2f} dollars."
print(myorder.format(quantity, itemno, price))

Output:
I want 3 pieces of item number 567 for 49.00 dollars.


...why? What benefit would you hope to gain?

Index number of what?

what do you mean? The f-string syntax uses direct refererences to the variables. If you wanted to have some indirection (IF it might improve readabilltiy), you could use another intermediate variable which can be changed but that sounds like it would make code worse

Did you try print(f"I want {quantity} pieces of item number {itemno} for {price:.2f} dollars.")? or myorder = f"I want {quantity} pieces of item number {itemno} for {price:.2f} dollars." --- because both worked when I ran them in ipython. So I'm not sure what you're asking.

quantity = 3
itemno = 567
price = 49
myorder = f"I want {quantity} pieces of item number {itemno} for {price:.2f} dollars."
print(myorder)

Output:
I want 3 pieces of item number 567 for 49.00 dollars.

Explanation
The f before the string indicates an f-string.
{quantity}, {itemno}, and {price:.2f}: These are placeholders where the values of quantity, itemno, and price (formatted to 2 decimal places) are inserted directly into the string.

F-string was added in Python 3.6 [python.org] so yes you can use F-string in Python 3.6 and above:
quantity = 3
itemno = 567
price = 49
myorder = F"I want {quantity} pieces of item number {itemno} for {price:.2f} dollars." #[1][2]
print(myorder)

[1] Format specifiers still remain the same.
[2] New in Python 3.12, you can now reuse the same quoting type of the outer F-string inside a replacement field when accessing dict() values using dict() keys.
